# x86 PAE mode paging

Tags: linux, operating-system, x86, x86-64

I have fair bit of knowledge about paging. However, I was just wondering if I can create 2 different level of paging structures from same cr3. (It is stupid. But just for kicks).

I am planning to create 3 level paging and 4 level paging on x86-64 bit machine from same cr3. Page size for 3 level paging would be 2MB and for 4 level would be 4KB.

Page directory would decide if it is going to point to page frame or to page table which then point to page frame.

I know this sounds complete crazy but I am planning to do it as a test case for a small project. Is this approach workable on x86-64 hardware?

Thanks

Comment: Existing OSes already mix large pages and small pages.

Comment: Oh ok and it is ok to do it with same cr3?

Comment: Take a look at the Page Size bit